# Creating a matching variable

Tags: r, match

I have a large dataset but showing a small sample of it

```
df = data.frame(v1 = c("Low", "Low", "High"), 
            v2 = c("Med", "High","Low"), 
            v3 = c("NA", "Low", "Low"),
            ID=c(1L, 1L, 1L),
            ID_name = c("AAA", "AA", "A"))
```

I need to count the number of matches for v1, v2, v3. For example, if v1 is Low, v2 is low and v3 is low, then the matching variable is 3. But NA's don't count towards match. For example, for the first row, the matching variable is only 1 as there is only 1 Low and 1 Med. I did this quickly in excel but need to do some permutation and have to figure out how to do it in r.

My final result should look like this:

```
df1 = data.frame(v1 = c("Low", "Low", "High"), 
             v2 = c("Med", "High","Low"), 
             v3 = c("NA", "Low", "Low"),
             ID=c(1L, 1L, 1L),
             ID_name = c("AAA", "AA", "A"),
             Consistency = c(1L,2L,2L))
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1$consistency = apply(df1[c("v1", "v2", "v3")], 1, function(x) max(table(x)))
```

We just want the number of occurrences of the most common value. `table` tabulates occurrences and does not count `NA`, so we just look at the max of the table.

Comment: Gregor, this works like magic and is easier! Thank you so much!

Comment: Gregor, the code above worked perfectly for smaller dataset. But for whatever reason, when i apply it to larger one with more missing values, i keep getting this error message _There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)_, and it gives weird Inf number when i summarize it. My old dataset had NAs too but somehow i never had this issue. Any suggestions what I can try? Thanks

Comment: Type `warnings()` and look at the first 50 warning messages. Maybe you have some all-NA rows? Maybe you can find a small subset of your data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I do have some rows with all NA's. Would that create a problem? This is what I am getting from the warnings() _Warning messages:
1: In max(table(x)) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(table(x)) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf_

Comment: Apparently so. `max(table(NA))` gives `-Inf`, along with that warning message. So that's what's happening. So just replace the `-Inf` in your results with whatever you want the result to be for an all-missing row. Or remove your all-missing rows first.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor. I will definitely try removing as later i need to simulate values and calculate the average match after that as well. Thanks for your help! You are the best.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `TRUE`/`FALSE` table where you compare all columns between each other (works only for small OP example) and use `rowSums` on it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(v1 == v2, v2 == v3, v1 == v3)]
#       V1    V2    V3
# 1: FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2: FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 3: FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# Final result
rowSums(setDT(df)[, .(v1 == v2, v2 == v3, v1 == v3)], na.rm = TRUE) + 1
# [1] 1 2 2
```

**Edit:**

If columns are factors:

```
setDT(df)
# Transform factors to character
df[, c("v1", "v2", "v3") := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = c("v1", "v2", "v3")]
df[, .(v1 == v2, v2 == v3, v1 == v3)]
```

Comment: I get an error message: "Error in Ops.factor(v1, v2) : level sets of factors are different".

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works. The real dataset is not a factor but somehow the created mock data is but with your suggestion even that was fixed. It works! Thanks PoGibas